# How to show all subarea of ​a country through openstreetmap API

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to use OpenStreetMap API to get all provinces, cities of a country.

However, when I read the API documentation, I don't know how to call all the cities of a certain country.

I hold a help. Thank you !